# Mobile touch "tap" event in flash pro CS6 using action script 3, keeps giving error as soon as I test the movie

Tags: flash, mobile, touch-event

I need help with the following code, I want to add Mobile touch tap event. I have added the code via code snippets panel.

The code executes if I am clicking in my published movie, but it gives me following eror as soon as I test it via touch settings in AIR Mobile debug launcher

"TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::TouchEvent@5fe2ec1 to flash.events.MouseEvent."......

```
// create all the cards, position them, and assign a randomcard face to each
for(var xx:uint=0;xx<boardWidth;xx++) { // horizontal
    for(var yy:uint=0;yy<boardHeight;yy++) { // vertical
    var c:card = new card(); // copy the movie clip card
    c.stop(); // stop on first frame
    c.x = xx*cardHorizontalSpacing+boardOffsetX; // set position
    c.y = yy*cardVerticalSpacing+boardOffsetY;
    var r:uint = Math.floor(Math.random()*cardList.length); // get a random face
    c.cardface = cardList[r]; // assign face to card
    cardList.splice(r,1); // remove face from list
    Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
    c.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, clickCard);
    c.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickCard); // have it listen for clicks
    trace(c.name);
    addChild(c); // show the card
    cardsLeft++;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the same event handler for mouse events and touch events.

Give your clickCard a TouchEvent:

And create a new function for mouseEvents, as the event handler for mouse events should have type MouseEvent

```
private function touchCard(e:TouchEvent):void
{
    // all touches
    const touches:Vector.<Touch> = e.getTouches(_q);
    // phase ending (finger release)?
    for each (var touch:Touch in touches)
    {
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.ENDED)
        {
            trace("Touch ended on card!");
        }
    }
}

private function clickCard(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    .. do stuff for mouses
}
```

obviously change your handlers in your code to point to these.

The reason you don't see the error when you publish maybe because publish movie might be set to run in a non debug version of flash player? maybe.